# SeekBar movement inbetween values

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I have a `SeekBar` with max value lets say 4 steps. now when I move the thumb from one value to another, the seekbar seems to be stucked/not moving, however I need to make it still movable but when I release the thumb it goes automatically to the nearest step/phase. Something like this library but using the default `SeekBar`

https://github.com/ademar111190/android-phased-seek-bar

Comment: maybe increase the number of steps

Comment: This is not a solution at all !